# selenium, os, python, удаленное управление

Tags: python, windows, selenium, windows-10, ос

Могут ли selenium и os управлять операционной системой (планируется windows 10) пользователя и его браузером, будучи установленными на удаленных серверах? Есть идея ставить клиенту только оболочку, а всю логику вынести на удаленный сервер. Хотелось бы хотя бы в кртаце услышать от гуру как это вообще должно работать. Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ и направления куда копать по этому вопросу, а так же за ссылки на литературу и примеры подобной реализации.

Comment: Да не, это бред